# overwriting register int failed in c programming

Tags: c, memory, int

I am wondering why the value of register integer `a` is not overwritten:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    register int a=10;
    {
        register int a=30;
    }
    printf("%d",a);
    getch();
}
```

Why isn't the value of `a` overwritten?  The output is showing `10`.

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm for coding and asking questions, but please, review your posts before submitting for grammar and formatting. "i" in reference to yourself should be capitalized, and use indentation with your code (4 spaces per new scope is a good rule of thumb). It just makes them hard to read otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having those braces inside your function creates a new *nested block*.  That means that your line:

```
register int a=30;
```

is declaring a *new variable* that also happens to be called `a`.  If you add another call to printf, you'll see that happening (I rewrote your program a bit to remove the unnecessary `register` keywords and cleaned up some things to make it be standard C, too):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    {
        int a = 30;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
  }
```

The output from this program is:

```
30
10
```

The inner `a` (the one set to `30`) is said to *shadow* the other local variable. You can create an arbitrary number of nestings, if you want.  For example, this next program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    {
        int a = 30;
        {
            int a = 40;
            printf("%d\n", a);
        }
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
40
30
10
```

The redeclarations of `a` hide *all other* declarations of `a` outside the current scope/block.  What all of this means is that your original program is semantically equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the inner `a` was set but never used.  In fact, turning on some warning flags might let the compiler give some diagnostic messages about what's going on.  I used `clang` here:

```
$ clang -Wunused-variable example.c -o example
example.c:7:9: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
    int a = 30;
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: ok i got that bro...but one questioni had                             the line register int a=30;
what it actually did in the code?

Comment: @WifuWifu, in your original program it does nothing.  It might as well not be there at all.

Answer (score 1):

You redeclare a variable in a new scope. The two a:s are different.

Try the following:

```
int main()
{
    register int a=10;
    {
       a=30;
    }
    printf("%d",a);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Those braces are unnecessary if there's no new scope required.  I'd get rid of them, too.

Comment: please explain how they are different?

Comment: @CarlNorum those are necessary for OP understanding the problem. This answer and the question is simply **meaningless** without them.

Comment: @WifuWifu, anytime you have two variables with the same name, only the one with the most-local scope is accessible.  For instance, if you made a global `int a = 12`, your program would still print `10`.

Comment: @H2CO3, the *question* is meaningless without them, but the answer isn't.  In particular making some mention of what those braces *do* in a more explicit way is probably a good idea.

Comment: I'll go write an answer and explain properly.

Comment: @Carl Norum. that's a question  in some programming forum..so can anyone explain the tehory behind it?